# declare multiple variable string for use in IN statement ('i','j')

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to concatenate a string such that I can use it on an in statement.  I'm getting an error:

> "incorrect syntax near '='."

Is what I'm doing possible?

```
DECLARE @Year uniqueidentifier = (SELECT TOP 1 y.des_zyearId FROM des_zyearset y WHERE y.des_YearText  = 2015)

--this is where I'm trying to concatenate

declare @heat varchar(70) = ('''' + (select top 1 fu.des_zfuelusagetypeId from des_zfuelusagetypeSet fu where = 'heat') + ', ' + (select top 1 fu.des_zfuelusagetypeId from des_zfuelusagetypeSet fu where = 'both') + '''')
```

Comment: because you don't define anything with `where` clause

Comment: just noticed that and now the error changed to "The data types varchar and uniqueidentifier are incompatible in the add operator." Perhaps my concatenation syntax is incorrect

Comment: try it `SomeColumn = cast(@Year as nvarchar(50))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @heat varchar(70) = 
('''' + (select top 1 fu.des_zfuelusagetypeId from des_zfuelusagetypeSet fu   
 where = 'heat' --->error here
)
 + ', ' + (select top 1 fu.des_zfuelusagetypeId from 
 des_zfuelusagetypeSet fu 
where = 'both'   --->error here
 ) + '''')
```

There are errors in the `select` statements. You are saying `where = 'heat'`, where it should be `where fu.somecolumn = 'heat'`. Similarly change it for the second `select`

Comment: just noticed that and now the error changed to "The data types varchar and uniqueidentifier are incompatible in the add operator."  Perhaps my concatenation syntax is incorrect?

Comment: just noticed that and now the error changed to "The data types varchar and uniqueidentifier are incompatible in the add operator." Perhaps my concatenation syntax is incorrect

Comment: change the datatype of @year to `varchar`